# convert Pandas column to string with special character separation

Tags: python, pandas

The df looks like

```
  type
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

The output should looks like

```
string="'a','b','c'"
```

I have used `df.type.str.cat(sep=',')` to add , in between but how to add quotation mark for each element?

Comment: `"'" + df.type.str.cat(sep="','") + "'"` crappy but should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) or [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
string = ','.join("'"+df['type']+"'")
```

Or:

```
string = ("'"+df['type']+"'").str.cat(sep=',')

string
"'a','b','c'"
```

Answer (score 1):

One other alternative may be to use `format` with `apply` and `sum`:

```
result = df.type.apply("'{}',".format).sum()[:-1]
```